# Add and remove border when clicking on a button JS

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, border, undo

hello I am struggling to use JS in order to make the buttons on my HTML page add a border to the button when it is clicked and to remove the border when it is clicked again. it works for the first 2 clicks but then no longer does anything after that. please excuse my js im extremely inexperienced.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var flag = true;
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

    function buttonFunction() {
    if (flag) {
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.add("buttonSelect");
        flag = false
        return
        });
    }
        } else {
        if (flag == false) {
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.add("buttonUnselect");
            flag = true
            return
        });
    }
        }
    }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue is you're adding both classes and never removing them.  Get rid of the `if else` statement and just toggle the class on click.  Don't need to wrap the loop in a function either. Just let the javascript execute the event listeners at runtime.

Also, make use of the `buttons` var you created instead of trying to query the DOM again for the same elements.

```
<script>
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("buttonSelect");
      })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This solves it, Thank you very much.